# The recyclerview crashes when I update it

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Please don't mark it as duplicate, as the solutions provided yesterday did not work.

I have populated a `recyclerview`, and it is working fine, albeit it loads a bit slowly.

However, say when I add a new name and update the `recyclerview` it crashes with the `NullPointerException`.

Below are the classes and code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mainOnes);
      recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleOnes);
      LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
      linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
      recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      populateList();

}

public void populateList(){
   DisplayUsersList displayUsersList = new DisplayUsersList();
   displayUsersList.execute();
}

public class DisplayUsersList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String postData) {
        try {
            list.clear();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(postData);
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                String forename = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("forename");
                String surname = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("surname");
                UserDetails userDetails  = new UserDetails(forename, musicName, surname);
                list.add(userDetails);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class AddUsers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String postData) {
        populateList();
    }
}
```

I think it is crashing because of the `populateList()` method call because I have already initialised everything

My logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at georgezs.userdas.UserDBGUI$DisplayUsersList.onPostExecute(UserDBGUI.java:218)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:741)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:197)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:654)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
```

Line 218 is `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

I tried instantiating the `recyclerview` in `onPostExecute` but it keeps crashing. My code works in the sense that it actually loads the data and displays it in a `recyclerview`. It just doesn't redisplay or reload when I call the `populateList()` method again.

This bug has been bugging me in my sleep literally - so any help and solutions would mean a lot to me

EDIT: I THINK I KNOW EXACTLY WHERE THE ERROR IS - IT IS IN THE POSTEXECUTE METHOD IN `ADDUSERS` CLASS.

Thanks

Comment: Why is `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` for?

Comment: I thought it was to align the recycler view

Comment: When you say you 'add a name'... how was it done? Is it in the same fragment/activity, or it is done as a separate fragment/activity? This piece of info might be vital of why the adapter gone null.

Comment: Nope. Can you please remove it and see what happens?

Comment: You do something that sets the adapter to null thats for sure.

Comment: Please post your adapter. You might not have checked if the list contains any data.

Comment: Not likely issue within the adapter, as the adapter is null. Hence posting the adapter code might not help.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the adapter is not null before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
if (adapter != null) {
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This happens because the AsyncTask executes asynchronously and by the time it finishes, the adapter might not be available anymore.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to update the data, so it should not be `null`

Comment: This might not address the answer, as that will basically not make the data updated. The question is why adapter is null.

Comment: Yes. The answer is not helpful

Comment: I am not sure why it is null. `populateList()` works `onCreate`

Comment: I think the error is in the `onPostExecute` method in the `AddUsers` class

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is, instead of using

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

replace with

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is assuming for whatever reason, you have got your `adapter` set to null, but not shown in the code clearly above, while your `recyclerview` is still fully intact.

p/s: I also didn't see you update your latest retrieved data and insert into the adapter. You might want to check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're handling variables outside the scope of your main class in a Threaded class which can always be sketchy. Granted AsyncTask is supposed to synchronize operations for you, I'm always cautious

Try passing your list and adapter to your DisplayUsersList class e.g.

```
DisplayUsersList displayUsersList = new DisplayUsersList(list, adapter);
displayUsersList.execute();
```

And in your DisplayUsersList make sure the reference of these is explicit e.g.

```
public class DisplayUsersList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private final List<UserDetails> list;
    private final Adapter adapter;

    public DisplayUsersList(List<UserDetails> list, Adapter adapter) {
        this.list = list;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
...
```

Also, try moving the populateList(); to OnStart rather than onCreate

[image]

As although the variables are assigned they may still be initialising.

**Edit**

Could you try moving the call to the top level class e.g.

```
public void dataSetChangedCallback() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in your DisplayUsersList change adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to

```
...
dataSetChangedCallback();
...
```

Comment: i tried moving the method to `onStart()` and I tried your solution - no luck, it still crashes

Comment: Could you post more of your solution or see my edit and let me know if that worked?